# Scrapping pdf links in dataframe from webpage using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract all the pdf links which takes us to the page directly from where we can download all the pdfs . I want to store these pdfs in a data frame

```html
url = "https://www.volvogroup.com/en/news-and-media/press-releases.html"
source = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text , "html.parser")
news_check = soup.find_all("a" , class_ = "articlelist__contentDownloadItem")
for i in news_check :
    print(i)
    break
    
data = set()
for i in soup.find_all('a'):
    for j in i.find_all('href'):
        pdf_link = "https://www.volvogroup.com" + j.get('.pdf')
        data.add(j)
        print(pdf_link)
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code to get pdf link:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.volvogroup.com/en/news-and-media/press-releases.html"
source = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(source.text , "html.parser")

news_check = soup.find_all("a" , class_ = "articlelist__contentDownloadItem")
    
data = set()

for i in news_check:
    pdf_link ="https://www.volvogroup.com"  + i['href']
    
    data.add(pdf_link)
    
    # for j in i.find_all('href'):
    #     pdf_link = + j.get('.pdf')
    #     data.add(j)
    #     print(pdf_link)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

**Output :**

```
0   https://www.volvogroup.com/content/dam/volvo-g...
1   https://www.volvogroup.com/content/dam/volvo-g...
2   https://www.volvogroup.com/content/dam/volvo-g...
3   https://www.volvogroup.com/content/dam/volvo-g...
4   https://www.volvogroup.com/content/dam/volvo-g...
5   https://www.volvogroup.com/content/dam/volvo-g...
6   https://www.volvogroup.com/content/dam/volvo-g...
7   https://www.volvogroup.com/content/dam/volvo-g...
8   https://www.volvogroup.com/content/dam/volvo-g...
9   https://www.volvogroup.com/content/dam/volvo-g...
10  https://www.volvogroup.com/content/dam/volvo-g...
11  https://www.volvogroup.com/content/dam/volvo-g...
12  https://www.volvogroup.com/content/dam/volvo-g...
```

Comment: well written code. upvoted.

Comment: The person asking the question used the `set` so I didn't change it anymore. If there was no special reason to use the `set` here, I could use the `list`. However, we can use the `set` to avoid duplicate data if we want. @D.L

Comment: `set` prevents duplicates, so it is better than `list`...

Comment: Of course, you're right.

Comment: it is actually one of the rare examples that I would use `set`. I like most tend just to use `list` for pretty much everything. So its cool.

Comment: only reason to use set was to avoid duplication as we are fetching the links